# How to validate window.prompt in javascript?

Tags: javascript, validation, user-input

Is there a way to validate the text of the input textBox of the prompt box displayed by calling window.prompt() in javascript?

I mean something like to not to close the prompt box when clicking its OK button if the string written in its input textBox contains numbers or other illegal chars defined by me, etc.

Comment: Not out of the box. You could respawn a prompt box right after the first one closes, though, or implement your own markup-based prompt dialog, or use one of many available.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var obj = {};

function validate( str ){
    return !! str; //or your own validation
}

function setName ( error_message ) {
    var name = prompt( (error_message || '') + "Enter a name: ");

    if ( ! validate( name ) ) {
        setName( 'Invalid name entered\n' );
    } else {
      obj.name = name;
    }
}
```

If you really want to use only `prompt` then this is the solution. But, I'd suggest you to use a modal dialog or create your own component.

Answer (score 2):

No, there is not.

`.prompt` is native functionality that can't be modified.

If you want input validation, you're going to need to use a custom prompt. It might be worth looking into UI libraries [like jQueryUI](http://jqueryui.com/dialog/), for example.

Answer (score 0):

You can't validate the input of a prompt before closing it. You could simulate this by creating your own type of prompt, or using jQueryUI.

Answer (score 0):

I came across this exact problem today while writing a **bookmarklet** which requests user input.

It struck me that it's possible to validate `window.prompt` simply by using a `while loop`:

```
let promptedAnswer = null;

while (promptedAnswer !== 'spoon') {

  promptedAnswer = prompt('Complete this phrase: "There is no [ ]."');
}
```

**Working Example:**

```js
let chosenNumber = 0;

while ((chosenNumber < 1) || (chosenNumber > 10)) {

  chosenNumber = prompt('Choose a number between 1 and 10:');
}

console.log('Your chosen number is ' + chosenNumber);
```